# PHP Mongos Driver Falling Back to Secondary Shards

Tags: php, mongodb, sharding

In a production environment (meaning the shards are each replica sets), specifying two different shards in the connection line like so:

```
$m = new MongoClient("mongodb://mongos1.example.com:27017,mongos2.example.com:27017");
```

If mongos1,example.com fails, the PHP driver never seems to try to connect to mongos2.example.com. Is this specific to the driver, or is there a way to force it to connect (other than working around it by implementing separate try and catch blocks for each server).

Comment: those are not shards, they are mongos instances, I will need to tst this, the php driver should failover gracefully

Comment: You're right, sorry, they aren't shards. They're instances of mongos running on separate servers, and they're supposed to be connecting to a sharded cluster.

Comment: The PHP driver (and all mongodb drivers) should have automatic failover (see the [JIRA ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/JAVA-381)). Perhaps mongos2 is not reachable? You might be able to do some more poking around with [MongoLog](http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongolog.php).

Comment: @llovett of course that is the Java driver edition but the PHP driver should have one some where

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, everyone. We have specifically been testing this with one mongos driver or the other down just to make sure the failover was working, and it isn't. Is it possible there's something extra that needs to be configured, other than the line I have above? That's all I'm using to test the failover.

Comment: Please enable full driver logging (see http://php.net/mongolog.setcallback). This *should* work, but if it isn't please file a bug report on https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/PHP - including the output of the MongoLog logging please